# How to still execute finally block when the code is stopped through Task Scheduler?

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler, try-finally

I have this code example:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime


def log_info(message: str):
    with open('somefile.log', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{datetime.now()}: {message}\n')


try:
    log_info('Process started')
    time.sleep(1000)  # to simulate long running...
finally:
    log_info('Process ended')
```

When I run the code in PyCharm (even in debug mode with breakpoints) or just in console/terminal and after some time I stop the running, the message "Process ended" is still written to the file. This behavior is correct.
However if I create a task in Windows Task Scheduler, I run the task and stop it (through the Task Scheduler), the "Process ended" message is not logged.
How to fix it?

Comment: when you terminate a process in windows, the code stops executing. if log_info hasn't been already been called, then somefile.log won't be written.

Answer (score 2):

By stopping your program via Task Scheduler, the Python interpreter is unexpectedly stopping, and cannot reach the `finally` block. The `finally` block only applies when your program is able to run without unexpectedly stopping.